# How to fix warning in wordforms.txt during sphinx index?

Tags: sphinx

I am new to sphinx.
When I am rotate/start the index, it shows.

```
 WARNINGS:invalid mapping(must be exactly 1 destination keyword)(wordforms='Sufenta'>
 'Sufentanil Citrate Injection'). Fix your wordforms file 'usr/local/sphinx/var/data/wordforms.txt'.
```

But after rotating, it gives and then it shows `Rotated successfully` message also.
Functionality is ok. But I dont know, why every time it shows warning in wordform.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning says, you have a 'wordform' with multiple words on the 'destiniation' side.

Don't do that.

Fix your wordforms file.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

Comment: If my `wordform.txt` file like, 
`'Sufenta'>'Sufentanil'`, it will neglect that warning ?

Comment: If I want file like `'Sufenta cit injet'>
 'Sufentanil Citrate Injection'` means,what change will be required ?

Comment: `Cefuroxime Sodium Injection > Cefuroxime Sodium Injection` this one also gives warning ! why ?

Comment: You need to read about wordforms again. They are called WORDforms, not PHRASEforms. Having multiple words on the destination side doesnt work - hence the warning.